# Allow ssh for specific IP Address and block all other servers using /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny file

Tags: linux

Allow ssh connection for a set of ten IP Address and block all other IP's using hosts.allow and hosts.deny file. how to do this?

Comment: Voted to close - this is not a programming problem and should have been asked at e.g. [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 8):

`SSHD` will first check `/etc/hosts.allow` for entries. If there is no rule in `/etc/hosts.allow` which fits `SSHD` will go on checking `/etc/hosts.deny` for rules.

So you need to add:

`/etc/hosts.deny`

```
sshd: ALL EXCEPT LOCAL
```

to block every SSH connection, except localhost, which is not in `/etc/hosts.allow`.

`/etc/hosts.allow`

```
sshd: 192.168.178.10
sshd: 192.168.178.11
sshd: 192.168.178.10/255.255.255.0
```

to allow specific IPs. Last rule is an example for an IP range.

However using `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` is not the recommended method to allow `SSH` only for a few IPs. You should consider using `iptables` for that job.

You could allow `SSH` for a specific IP by using a rule like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED --source x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

If you want to use iptables you should have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221168/allow-ssh-for-specific-ip-address-and-block-all-other-servers-using-etc-hosts-a/32222907#32222907).

Comment: Instead of LOCAL in sshd: ALL EXCEPT x.x.x.x can i give the IP of my server?

Comment: [root@ etc]# cat /etc/hosts.allow
sshd:10.203.38.194
[root@ etc]# cat /etc/hosts.deny
sshd: ALL EXCEPT 10.203.38.194

This is how the files look, now i couldn't access this server itself.

Comment: thats odd. Login via VNC and check `/var/log/messages`

Comment: After removing the line sshd: ALL EXCEPT 10.203.38.194 from hosts.deny file i could able to access the server, but not only from that server from other servers also,..

Comment: thats what you should expect if there are no entries in /etc/hosts.deny. Maybe the root cause of the error is the service name of sshd. Otherwise I would try again with the hosts.deny as above. You should also check that you allow the correct IP. Maybe there is a gateway between your client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found and example of how to block ips or allow ips with allow and deny hosts files

Path file `/etc/hosts.allow`

```
sshd : 192.168.0.1: allow
sshd : 192.168.0.2: allow

#add the ips that you want
sshd : 192.168.0.3: allow    

#example of localhost
sshd : localhost : allow

#example 192.168.0.x subnet
192.168.0.

# for 192.168.x.x subnet
192.168.

#add this at the end
sshd : ALL : deny
```

Source [**"Limit ssh access by IP address"**](https://coderwall.com/p/yz-2_a/limit-ssh-access-by-ip-address)
and other example [**"TCP Wrappers Configuration Files"**](https://www.centos.org/docs/rhel-rg-en-3/s1-tcpwrappers-access.html)

### Warning

> If the last line of a hosts access file is not a newline character (created by pressing the [Enter] key), the last rule in the file fails and an error is logged to either /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure. This is also the case for a rules that span multiple lines without using the backslash. The following example illustrates the relevant portion of a log message for a rule failure due to either of these circumstances:`warning: /etc/hosts.allow, line 20: missing newline or line too long`

Comment: does this subnet mask allowed `192.168.0.1/14` since i want to  filter region ip address .

Comment: Do not follow this advice!!! It made me lose all connection with my server even though the allow IP address was correct.

Comment: Every allow line MUST look like this:
sshd : IPADRES or RANGE